# Unexpected token : in JSON on heroku, runs fine locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, heroku

The line in question:

```
render(json: {'token': token} ) and return
```

> /app/app/controllers/authentications_controller.rb:29: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting =>
>                   render(json: {'token': token} ) and return

I can

```
rails s
```

locally just fine.

What gives?

Comment: I don't know but I'd try changing `:` to `=>`. If you have this code in a bunch of places, then maybe not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{'token': token}` won't work in Ruby (yet), you would have to use `{'token' => token}` for keys which are strings.